# capturing group under capturing group?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is possible to capturing group under capturing group so i can have an array like that

`regex = (asd1).(lol1),(asd2).(asd2)`

`string = asd1.lol1,asd2.lol2`

- `return_array[0]=>group[0]='asd1';`
- `return_array[0]=>group[1]='lol1';`
- `return_array[1]=>group[0]='asd2';`
- `return_array[1]=>group[1]='lol2';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using regular expressions can get what you want, you could also use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok) to iterate through what seems to simply be comma separated sets:

```
$results = array();
$str = 'asd1.lol1,asd2.lol2';

$token = strtok($str, ',');
while ($token !== false) {
    $results[] = explode('.', $token, 2);
    $token = strtok(',');
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd1
            [1] => lol1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd2
            [1] => lol2
        )
)
```

With regular expressions your pattern needs to only include the two terms surrounding a period, i.e.:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=^|,)(\w+)\.(\w+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The `(?<=^|,)` is a look-behind assertion; it makes sure to only match what comes after if preceded by either the start of your search string or a comma, but it doesn't "consume" anything.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd1.lol1
            [1] => asd1
            [2] => lol1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd2.lol2
            [1] => asd2
            [2] => lol2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `preg_match_all`.

```
$regex = '/^((\w+)\.(\w+)),((\w+)\.(\w+))$/';
$string = 'asd1.lol1,asd2.lol2';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

This function will create a 2-dimensional array, where the first dimension represents the matched groups (i.e. the parentheses, `0` contains the whole matched string though) and each have subarrays to all the matched lines (only 1 in this case).

```
[0] => ("asd1.lol1,asd2.lol2")  // a view of $matches
[1] => ("asd1.lol1")
[2] => ("asd1")
[3] => ("lol1")
[4] => ("asd2.lol2")
[5] => ("asd2")
[6] => ("lol2")
```

Your best bet to have groups is to process the first dimension of the array that you want and to then process them further, i.e. get "asd1.lol1" from `1` and `4` and then process these further into `asd1` and `lol1`.

You wouldn't need as many parentheses in your first run:

```
$regex = '/^(\w+\.\w+),(\w+\.\w+)$/';
```

will yield:

```
[0] => ("asd1.lol1,asd2.lol2")
[1] => ("asd1.lol1")
[2] => ("asd2.lol2")
```

Then you can split the array in `1` and `2` into more granular values.

Flags can be set to `preg_match_all` to order the output differently. Particularly, `PREG_SET_ORDER` allows you to have all matched instances in the same subarray. This is of little importance if you're only processing one string, but if you're matching a pattern in a text, it might be more convenient to have all info about one match in `$matches[0]`, and so forth.

---

Note that if you're just separating a string by comma and then by any periods, you might not need regular expressions and could conveniently use `explode()` as so:

```
$string = 'asd1.lol1,asd2.lol2';
$matches = explode(',', $string);
foreach($matches as &$match) {
    $match = explode('.', $match);
}
```

This will give you exactly what you want, but do note that you don't have as much control over the process as with regular expressions – for instance, `asd1.lol1.lmao,asd2.lol2.rofl.hehe` will also work and they'll produce bigger arrays than you may want. You can check with `count()` on the size of the subarray and handle the cases when the array isn't of the appropriate size, though. I still believe that's more comfortable than using regular expressions.

Comment: You can use `PREG_SET_ORDER` to rearrange the result set :)

Comment: @Jack Thanks – I've added a (very lazy) paragraph mentioning `PREG_SET_ORDER`. I hope you don't mind

Comment: Right, I didn't realise that your pattern captures too much :) if it only captures two dot separated values it'd be more useful to use set ordering.